# Can anybody please explain why this limit is not zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, intuition

$$\lim_{x\to0} \Im \left((-1)^x \Gamma(x)\right)=-\pi$$

It seems the imaginary part of $(-1)^x$ should be zero at integer points, including $0$ and the other factor is always real.

Here is a plot (imaginary part is dotted):

Comment: For info, Wolfram Alpha gives $\pi$ (not $-\pi$) as the limit

Comment: @Klangen I plotted the graphic of this function and it is definitely $-\pi$

Comment: How should $(-1)^x$ be interpreted? $\exp(\pi i x)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I assume so as $x\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Mathematica plots it as the above

Comment: So apparently Mathematica writes $-1$ as $\exp(-\pi i)$. Probably it restricts the argument of complex numbers to the interval $[-\pi, \pi)$. One of many legitimate choices.

Comment: @Klangen For me WolframAlpha gives $-\pi$: https://tinyurl.com/ulkgulc

Comment: @Klangen Since the question states "the other factor is always real", $x$ is probably even restricted to be real. The limit wouldn't exist if $x \to 0$ would consider all complex $x$ (of small modulus).

Comment: @Klangen how did you get $\pi$ in Wolfram Alpha? Can you provide URL?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, Mathematica defines $(-1)^x$ as $\exp(i\pi x)$.

Comment: Not according to that plot, @Anixx. $\sin (\pi x)$ is positive for $0 < x < 1$, $\Gamma(x)$ is positive for $x > 0$. Thus $\Im \bigl(\exp(i\pi x)\Gamma(x)\bigr) > 0$ for $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok I found the error, my bad. I was using $(-1)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

The limit is nonzero because $\Gamma$ has a pole at $0$ which annihilates the zero of of the sine there.

The value of the limit depends on how you define $(-1)^x$. The usual ways define it as $\exp (m\pi i x)$ with an odd integer $m$. Most commonly used is $m = 1$. With Euler's formula $\exp (iz) = \cos z + i\sin z$ we then have (for real $x$ not a non-positive integer)
$$\Im \bigl((-1)^x\Gamma(x)\bigr) = \Gamma(x)\sin (m\pi x).$$
Using the functional equation of $\Gamma$ it follows that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \Im \bigl((-1)^x\Gamma(x)\bigr) = \lim_{x \to 0} \bigl(x\Gamma(x)\bigr)\frac{\sin (m\pi x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \Gamma(1+x)\frac{\sin (m\pi x)}{x} = m\pi.$$

A limit of $-\pi$ thus corresponds to the choice $m = -1$.

Comment: Isn't $\sin0$ equal to 0?

Comment: Sure, but $\Gamma$ has a pole at $0$ (simple, with residue $1$, so if $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $0$ with $f(0) = 0$, then $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)\Gamma(z) = f'(0)$).